# Inserting data in calls content provider fails calls application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to insert data into call log and retrieving it back the application runs fine but no data is displayed in the activity my code is as follows.

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Calls.CACHED_NAME, "Chaitanya");

    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Calls.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

The uri is also receives a value but the cursor doesn't return any record.

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    projection, null, null, null);
```

This cursor is then used to display the data.

After the execution of program if calls or calllog application is launched it shows exception.

What could be the possible problem with the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added needed right to your application.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You added just a name into database. Try adding some more informations like call type, date, duration ...

Comment: yes I have tried the code below but same problem persist      `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, 13232);
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.DURATION, 0);
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE);
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, "");
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
  values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");`

Comment: I tried it on my Galaxy S with some custom rom and it worked. Added call is shown in my calllog. I added CACHED_NAME( not in my contacts ) but it wasn't shown. Just number was shown.

Comment: Leave out Cached names. They are for queries, not for inserts. If you want to show a name, create a contact for the number.